# Is it possible to bound the range checked by check_partials?

Tags: openmdao

I have a component that includes `np.sqrt(1-x)`. This works fine for normal operation, since all inputs will strictly be between 0 and 1. However, when checking partials and providing an input array that goes all the way up to 1, the finite differencer will step past 1, and break the component. The inputs shouldn't be less than 0 either, so simply switching the direction of the finite difference wouldn't work.

The workaround is just using `np.linspace(0, 0.99, 400)` instead of `np.linspace(0, 1, 400)`.

Is it possible to set allowable bounds for the finite differencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of V3.1 there isn't a way to set bounds like that. Just make sure that you test the derivatives around a more well posed point, like around 0.5.

If you're having trouble getting things to work in the optimization context, since you might bump into both bounds ... well, thats why analytic derivatives are better :)

Comment: This also is also one of the few cases where switching the form to 'backward' instead of the default 'forward' would help.